# Переменные окружения при запуске Python скрипта (Mac os)

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

В скрипте есть загрузка переменных окружения

```
 host = os.getenv('FIREBASE_CHHOST')
 port = os.getenv('FIREBASE_CHPORT')
```

Подскажите, как правильно их задавать при запуске скрипта?
Скрипт запускаю командой

> python3 file.py

Так же пробовал сначала запустить bash файл, в нем прописывал

```
#!/bin/bash
export FIREBASE_CHHOST='server'
```

Но в python скрипте все равно не находи переменную.

Comment: у вас CHOST и CHHOST в вопросе. может опечатка?

Comment: @xmikex да, действительно опечатался, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже содержимое файла баш скрипта

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export YOUR_VARIABLE='value'
python3 file.py
```

> Почитайте про `venv` не запускайте файлы проекта в реальной OS. Там и переменные окружения можно настроить при запуске `venv`

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант это задать окружение непосредственно для одной команды:

```
env FIREBASE_CHHOST=somevalue FIREBASE_CHPORT=othervalue python3 file.py
```